# UICollectionView cellForItemAt indexPath strange order

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

The problem is that when I scroll my collectionView the things are going well, I get indexPath with item : **1,2,3,4,5**, but then, suddenly **150,151,152**.
Can some one help me what is going on here ?

I do use:

```
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
```

and

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9

    let autoLayoutAttributes = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 40)
    let autoLayoutSize = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow)
    let autoLayoutFrame = CGRect(origin: autoLayoutAttributes.frame.origin, size: autoLayoutSize)
    autoLayoutAttributes.frame = autoLayoutFrame
    return autoLayoutAttributes

}
```

**When you scroll first 5 cells appearing, and then suddenly last 10.        But after you begin to scroll up ( when you have seen last 10 ), the between cells begin appearing. It just jumps from begining to the end and then begins to load mid cells.**

Comment: What do you care what order things come in? Yours not to reason why, yours to answer the question that `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` asks you. If you can't immediately answer it for any index path, you're doing something wrong. If you can immediately answer it, move on.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You talk about the indexPath being in a strange order none of your code has anything to do with indexPath. It's all about layout.

Comment: @rmaddy the `autoLayoutAttributes` contains an index path

Comment: but it is not correct, when do you scroll a chat or comments, and you read first 5, and then last 10....

Comment: but after you begin to scroll up ( when you have seen last 10 ), the between ones begin appearing.

Comment: it just jumps from begining to the end and then begins to load mid cells.

Comment: may be some advices ?